# Translating 2 place predicates

Tags: predicate-logic, logic-translation

Hi Having some trouble translating these:

Everbody likes Ray or Lucy. is it asfollows:

"∀x∃x[love'(Ray(x)+lucy)] ?

and for nobody likes the teacher
   ¬∃x likes'(teacher) ??

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is a bit strange. Assuming an appropriate universe of people, I would expect something more like:
$$
\forall x \, [\textsf{Likes}(x, \textsf{Ray}) \lor \textsf{Likes}(x, \textsf{Lucy})] \\
\neg \exists x \, [\textsf{Likes}(x, \textsf{Teacher})]
$$

Comment: Ok thankyou. Haven't done this before - 
so in 'everbody likes ray or lucy' is (x) people who like?
and in no body likes the teacher (x) is the set of people who like the teacher?

Comment: There aren't really any sets. If I were to literally interpret the notation I used, I would read it as: "For each person $x$, either $x$ likes Ray, or $x$ likes Lucy, or $x$ likes both Ray and Lucy." and "It is not the case that there exists some person $x$ such that $x$ likes the teacher."